# jquery download image (data:image) link not working for Ipad but working fine in window

Tags: jquery, ipad, iso

I have the following jquery code use to downloaded the image into the computer when user click on the link.

```
    $("a#downloadLink").on("click", function () {
        var d = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace(/-/g, "");
        $(this).attr("href", $("#openLargeImage").val()).attr("download", "image-" + d + ".jpg");
    });
```

It's work perfectly fine when run in the computer. However, it's working differently when page is open in Ipad's safari (it's open the image in the page instead of download the image into the Ipad).

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue? So that it will download the image into the Ipad instead of open the image on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code: `touchstart`

```
$("a#downloadLink").on("click touchstart", function () {
    var d = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace(/-/g, "");
    $(this).attr("href", $("#openLargeImage").val()).attr("download", "image-" + d + ".jpg");
});
```

Comment: I have tried the code above, still the same, when click on the link in safari, it will open the image in the page instead of downloading it into the Ipad. However, it's working fine for window